# StaggeredGridLayoutManager returns wrong verticalScrollOffset

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm doing almost the same as here (https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager), but with RecyclerView in tabs.

RecyclerView in one tab has items with big height and the first one is not always fully visible under header.
At some point I call RecyclerView's computeVerticalScrollOffset() (that calls StaggeredGridLayoutManager's method) and it returns completely wrong values. If I change header height to make first item fully visible I'm getting right values.

Is there any known solution/fix for this?

P.S. I also use LinearLayoutManager and always get right values even if first item is not fully visible under header

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error is with the findFirstVisiblePosition() and findLastVisiblePosition() used in the computeScrollOffset() function arguments. Even if I use almost equal row height computeVerticalScrollOffset() returns really weird numbers.
If we replace them with the recyclerView.getChildAt(0) and recyclerView.getChildAt(recyclerView.getChildCount() - 1) that actually works.

So we can write our own function:

```
View firstItemView = recyclerView.getChildAt(0);
View lastItemView = recyclerView.getChildAt(recyclerView.getChildCount() - 1);

int firstItem = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(firstItemView);
int lastItem = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(lastItemView);
int itemsBefore = firstItem;

int laidOutArea = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getDecoratedBottom(lastItemView) - recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getDecoratedTop(firstItemView);
int itemRange = lastItem - firstItem + 1;
float avgSizePerRow = (float) laidOutArea / itemRange;

int offset = (int) (itemsBefore * avgSizePerRow + recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getPaddingTop() - recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getDecoratedTop(firstItemView));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the source code of `RecyclerView`:

```
@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollOffset() {
    return mLayout.canScrollVertically() ? mLayout.computeVerticalScrollOffset(mState) : 0;
}
```

mLayout is an instance of `LayoutManager`. In our case, it should belong to `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`. Let's check there:

```
@Override
public int computeVerticalScrollOffset(RecyclerView.State state) {
    return computeScrollOffset(state);
}
```

then here:

```
private int computeScrollOffset(RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    ensureOrientationHelper();
    return ScrollbarHelper.computeScrollOffset(state, mPrimaryOrientation,
            findFirstVisibleItemClosestToStart(!mSmoothScrollbarEnabled, true)
            , findFirstVisibleItemClosestToEnd(!mSmoothScrollbarEnabled, true),
            this, mSmoothScrollbarEnabled, mShouldReverseLayout);
}
```

And finally we go to ScrollbarHelper.computeScrollOffset:

```
/**
 * @param startChild View closest to start of the list. (top or left)
 * @param endChild   View closest to end of the list (bottom or right)
 */
static int computeScrollOffset(RecyclerView.State state, OrientationHelper orientation,
        View startChild, View endChild, RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm,
        boolean smoothScrollbarEnabled, boolean reverseLayout) {
    if (lm.getChildCount() == 0 || state.getItemCount() == 0 || startChild == null ||
            endChild == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    final int minPosition = Math.min(lm.getPosition(startChild),
            lm.getPosition(endChild));
    final int maxPosition = Math.max(lm.getPosition(startChild),
            lm.getPosition(endChild));
    final int itemsBefore = reverseLayout
            ? Math.max(0, state.getItemCount() - maxPosition - 1)
            : Math.max(0, minPosition);
    if (!smoothScrollbarEnabled) {
        return itemsBefore;
    }
    final int laidOutArea = Math.abs(orientation.getDecoratedEnd(endChild) -
            orientation.getDecoratedStart(startChild));
    final int itemRange = Math.abs(lm.getPosition(startChild) -
            lm.getPosition(endChild)) + 1;
    final float avgSizePerRow = (float) laidOutArea / itemRange;

    return Math.round(itemsBefore * avgSizePerRow + (orientation.getStartAfterPadding()
            - orientation.getDecoratedStart(startChild)));
}
```

And we should focus on last statement. This method returns the offset calculated by items * avgHeight, which isn't accurate when our items have variety of height.

As a result, when we use a `LinearLayoutManager` of `GridLayoutManager`, since height of each row is confirmed, `computeVerticalScrollOffset()` will return correct distance. However, unfortunately, when we use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, we cannot get accurate scroll offset by it.

**P.S** I know the reason why it isn't correct, but I don't know how to get correct scroll distance. If anyone knows, please visit: [How to get correct scroll distance of RecyclerView when using a StaggeredGridLayoutManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30805156/how-to-get-correct-scroll-distance-of-recyclerview-when-using-a-staggeredgridlay) and post your answer.