# How to get correct scroll distance of RecyclerView when using a StaggeredGridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I created a header view by creating and binding a unique `ViewHolder` in `RecyclerView` due to special view type. The header is totally blank but it is full-span and its height is calculated very well for following animations when user scrolls the `RecyclerView`:

- A `TextView` will move from the center of header view to `Toolbar` and finally "becomes" title of it. During the process, the TextView will shrink according to vertical offset.
- Another `TextView` will move with the first `TextView` at the same time but it won't shrink. Instead, it will change alpha and finally become transparent when the first `TextView` is at correct position in `Toolbar`.

To implement them, I need to get the scroll distance of `RecyclerView` so that I can calculate translationY or alpha.

Here is what I've done now:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        private int totalDy = 0;

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            totalDy -= dy;

            // setAlpha, setTranslationY and setScale here according to totalDy.
        }
    });
```

It works fine when dataset doesn't change. However, when I scroll down, insert/remove any items to/from the adapter and `notifyItemInserted/Removed()`, the totalDy won't be accurate. For example, when I removed an item, totalDy won't go back 0 any more.

As a result, it seems that using totalDy to get scroll distance of `RecyclerView` won't work well. Are there any ways for developers to get it?

**NOTICE:** What I am using is a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and I feel it is different from `LinearLayoutManager`.